# Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Unexpected token

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs

new to parse and react and I'm I'm getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 50: Unexpected token
>
> observe: function() {

How can I fix it ?

Here is my whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href=&#39;http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400&#39; rel=&#39;stylesheet&#39; type=&#39;text/css&#39;>
  <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.13.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script> 
    <!-- Now include parse-react.js -->
    <script src="https://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-react.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>

<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="./velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="./react.js"></script>
<script src="./JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">

    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    var App = React.createClass({   
        render: function() {        
            var name=null;
            var password=null;
            var email=null;
        
            return (
                <div>
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" ref="name"  /><br/>
        
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input type="password" ref="password" /><br/>
 
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input type="email" ref="email"  /><br/>
 
                  <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>
                    Save and Continue
                  </button>
                </div>
              )
          },
 
          saveAndContinue: function(e) {
              e.preventDefault()
              //debugger;
              // Get values via this.refs
              data = {
                  name: this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value,
                  password: this.refs.password.getDOMNode().value,
                  email: this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value,
              }
              //this.props.saveValues(data)
          },     
    
          //this.props.nextStep()
  
          saveValues: function()
          {
              return function()
              {
                  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin],    
                  observe: function() {
                      return {
            
                      };
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  );

  React.renderComponent(<App />,  document.body);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Since I'm new to this so Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`saveValues` is a function that returns a function. Within the returned function body you seem to attempt to use object literal syntax.

```
function() {
    a: "something",
    b: "something else"
}
```

is not valid syntax. You probably mean to return some object.

Comment: I was following this tutorial and it told me to do this 
[link](http://viget.com/extend/building-a-multi-step-registration-form-with-react) and I'm trying to use some parse with it

Comment: If you check the `saveValues` implementation in the tutorial it's not the same as your code. Your code has invalid syntax, the tutorial code doesn't.

Comment: Why the tutorial code uses an IIFE in `saveValues` is entirely unclear to me, but the syntax is correct. And the code is completely different from yours. You have probably copied-and-pasted incorrectly.